# Sitecore 9 xProfile no data

Tags: experience-profile

Hey guys anyone got the xProfile working properly on SC 9?

I have data on analytics, I'm identifying the contact with

`Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs`

Using fiddler, I can see when I abandon the session the xConnect is called to record the interactions. I even see the identifier with the user I identified. Everything looks correct but yet when I open xProfile, I get no error whatsoever (client console or SC log).

Any ideas?

**Update (1)**

Also if I use a console app and get the contact using the code below I get all interations / goals of that user as expected

```
var contact = client.Get(contactReference, new ContactExpandOptions()
{
    FacetKeys = { PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey },
    Interactions = new RelatedInteractionsExpandOptions()
    {
        StartDateTime = DateTime.MinValue,
        EndDateTime = DateTime.MaxValue,
        Limit = int.MaxValue
    }
});
```

**Update (2)**

Also, there is no data on my solr core `SITENAME_xdb`

**Solved --**

The issue was that I renamed the database changed the connection strings but the connection strings are also stored in the database (don't really like this) so have a look at `ShardMapManager.ShardsGlobal` table.

Comment: Can you verify ContactIdentifiers table into yourdbprefix_Xdb.Collection.Shard0 ?

Comment: Hi @SitecoreClimber, that table is empty, what does that mean?

Comment: it means your contacts wasn't saved. Can you verify xConnect logs

Comment: Hi @SitecoreClimber thx for the help I think I know what is happening but I need some help still.
I had installd SC 9 to do some tests, then I decided to go ahead and duplicate databases and change the name of DB connection strings etc...
I just noticed that it is saving on a different DB but I jsut don't understand how since all connection strings are changed, do you have any idea?

Comment: Ha got it, thx for the help without it I wouldn't figure it out.
the name of the server is stored in a table in the database 
ShardMapManager.ShardsGlobal so just changing connectionstring is not enough (not sure if I like this)

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it

The issue was that I renamed the database changed the connection strings but the connection strings are also stored in the database (don't really like this) so have a look at ShardMapManager.ShardsGlobal table :)